# How to see how much 2 segments overlap in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

I want to see the amount of traffic that is in both "Segment A" and "Segment B". Can I do that in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is called a multi-segment view.

To apply Segments to a report:
    Sign in to your Google Analytics account.
    Open the View that includes the reports you want to use.
    Click the Reporting tab, then open the report you want.

For example I will use Audience Overview report.
    At the top of your report, click + Add Segment...

[image]